# Primefaces link open an email compose window

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

With JSF-Primefaces how can I make a link on a dataTable column for emailId, such that onclick will open an email compose window?
I'm using Primefaces.3.0.M3 with JSF2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the HTML standard [`mailto:` link syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html#mailto-url). You just need to make sure that the generated HTML link ends up to look like

```html
<a href="mailto:john.doe@example.com?subject=Some%20subject&amp;body=Some%20body">mail</a>
```

This can in JSF be achieved by for example

```html
<h:outputLink value="mailto:#{user.email}">
    <f:param name="subject" value="Some subject" />
    <f:param name="body" value="Some body" />
    <h:outputText value="mail" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Those links will open the client's default mail composition editor. The `subject` and `body` parameters are optional and allows you to set a default subject and body in the email editor.

Comment: By using the JSF method, it escapes my subject and body : `Some+subject` and `Some+body` respectively.  Anyway to get around this (which would make for a more elegant solution)?

Comment: Same problem here and no solution.

Comment: Just press "Ask Question" button then?

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that the JSF tag `h:outputLink` escapes the subject and body as query parameters, replacing spaces with `+` instead of `%20`.

The good news is that you can achieve the correct result with [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class:

```java
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("mailto", "your@email.com", "subject=Some subject&body=Some body"); 
String result = "mailto:?" + uri.getRawFragment();
assert result.equals("mailto:?subject=Some%20subject&body=Some%20body");
```

Note that the first two arguments in the constructor are irrelevant.

You can use the `result` in the `href` attribute of your JSF/Primefaces tag, such as `h:outputLink` or `p:button` which opens the default e-mail client with a pre-defined subject and body and an empty recipient address.